# How to deserialize complex json response in poco using restsharp when model classes are defined separately for each section

Tags: c#, model, restsharp, json-deserialization, poco

Hi I am new to RestSharp and C#. I am trying to deserialize a complex JSON response into a POCO using `RestResponse<T>` from RestSharp. The issue is that the response has a nested structure like `Dictionary<List<Dictionary<key,object>>>` but the model classes are defined separately, which means for `List` objects there is a separate class and for the overall `Dictionary` there is no class or object defined.

How can I deserialize this?

```
// Root.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MStestPracticeProject.Models.ModelsForGetPracticeDirectory
{
    public class Root
    {
        public List<Workspace> workspaces { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
// Workspace.cs
using System;
namespace MStestPracticeProject.Models.ModelsForGetPracticeDirectory
{
    public class Workspace
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string visibility { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In `testClass` I am trying the following which doesn't work because `RestResponse<T>` needs a proper POCO class.

```
RestResponse<Dictionary<"workspace", List<Root>>> restResponse =
    restClient.ExecuteGet<Dictionary<"workspace", List <Root>>>(restRequest);
```

How should I approach this type of deserialization?

Comment: You can use https://json2csharp.com/ to convert the JSON into matching classes. If that doesn't work for you please provide the exceptions you are getting and an example of the JSON you're trying to deserialize.

Comment: Doing that you probably want to deserialize directly to the `Root` type: `restClient.ExecuteGet<Root>(restRequest)`